# jQuery Mobile popup dynamic contents are not refreshed

Tags: javascript, android, html, jquery-mobile, popup

I have a common JQM popup across multiple pages. From each page, the contents of popup are refreshed using the data from page. On the first load of the page I can see the refreshed contents on popup. However, when I load new data onto popup div, I still get the older data on popup widget.

If I examine the innerHTML of the popup, it gives me new contents but cannot see them on the popup.

Here is my example code:

```
    <body>
    <div id="common-popup">

       <div id="data-popup" data-role="popup">';
         <p>Name: N/A<p> 
         <p>DOB: N/A <p>
       </div> <!--Popup div ends -->
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
        <input type='text' id='p1_name' value=''>Name: </input>
        <input type='text' id='p1_dob' value=''>DOB: </input>
        <button class="update-data" id="b1"/>
       <a href="#data-popup"> Watch Data </a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="page2">
        <input type='text' id='p2_name'>Name: </input>
        <input type='text' id='p2_dob'>DOB: </input>
        <button class="update-data" id="b2"/>
        <a href="#data-popup"> Watch Data </a>
    </div>
   </body>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('.update-data').on('vclick', function(){
      var id = $(this).id;
          id = id.split('');
       var htm = '<div id="data-popup" data-role="popup">';
           htm += '<p>Name: ' + $('#p' + id[1] + '_name').val()  +'<p>';
           htm += '<p>Name: ' + $('#p' + id[1] + '_name').val()  +'<p>';

         $('#common-popup').html(htm).trigger('create');
     });

</script>
```

In the above code if I examine the innerHTML using:

console.log("Common Inner Html: " +  document.getElementById('common-popup').innerHTML);

I can see the updated contents, however when I open the pupup, I still see the older contents. Please let me know how to refresh the contents on popup

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bhavik89/49QwL/1/

In the Fiddle I can only see the initial contents, they are not refreshed upon the update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of putting the popup in a DIV, just leave it under the body. Then when recreating it, leave the top level DIV there and just replace the contents:

```
<div id="data-popup" data-role="popup" data-theme="a" >
   <div >
       <p>Name: N/A</p> 
       <p>DOB: N/A </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Make sure your link has data-rel="popup":

```
<a href="#data-popup" data-rel="popup"> Watch Data </a>
```

Give your update button some text so we can see the button:

```
<button class="update-data" id="b1" >Update</button>
```

With this in place initialize the popup on document ready and then on the update button click, replace the popup HTML, call enhanceWithin() and finally call popup("refresh") to update the popup widget:

```
$(function(){
    $("#data-popup").enhanceWithin().popup();
});

$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){
   $('.update-data').on('vclick', function(){
      var id = $(this).prop("id");
          id = id.split('');

       var htm = '<div>';
           htm += '<p>Name: ' + $('#p' + id[1] + '_name').val()  +'<p>';
           htm += '<p>DOB: ' + $('#p' + id[1] + '_dob').val()  +'<p>';
           htm +=  '</div>';

       $("#data-popup").html(htm).enhanceWithin().popup("refresh");       
   });    
});
```

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/7HVGR/2/)**

Comment: That really worked!!, Thanks you made my day!. The reason I was creating popup inside the <div> was because in my actual app, there are many similar popups created dynamically, I found it reasonable to place all dynamic popups within a <div>. However your method works for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Bhavik, you can still put the popups inside a DIV: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/7HVGR/3/

Comment: I am getting error in console, Uncaught Error: no such method 'refresh' for popup widget instance. even demo fiddle also have this error in console.

Comment: @KaranPatel, you are correct. leave off the .popup("refresh"):  http://jsfiddle.net/7HVGR/61/